# Invoke a method of a class which is implemented in her supperclass

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class java ProductManager which extends another class with the same name,
located in another project with another package("com.services") .

I have to invoke a method deleteProduct(Long productId) located in the super-class.

```
try{
   Object service = CONTEXT.getBean("ProductManager");
   Method method = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("deleteProduct", Long.class);
   method.invoke(service, productId);
} catch(Exception e){
   log.info(e.getMessage());
}
```

I couldn't delete the product:
I get this info:

```
com.franceFactory.services.ProductManager.deleteProduct(java.lang.Long)
```

the product isn't deleted :(

Comment: Is method you are trying to invoke public? Is this method overridden in your class?

Comment: yes, it's public, but it isn't overridden in my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various [`getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) and [`getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) only return methods declared on the current class instance. From the javadoc:

> This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.

The important part here is "*but excludes inherited methods*". This is why you are getting an exception with your code as it currently stands, it is not returning the `deleteProduct()` method from the parent class.

Instead if you wanted to continue using reflection you would need to use the [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) method as this returns all public methods, "*including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces*."

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use reflection then don't use `getDeclaredMethod()` because (as its name suggest) it can return only methods *declared in current class*, while you claim you want to invoke method declared in other class (to be precise declared in super class).

To get public method (including also inherited ones) use `getMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your are overriding that method, just use the reserved word [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) (from the Oracle documents):

```
public class Superclass {

    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod(); // This calls to the method defined in the superclass
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

This code will write:

> Printed in Superclass.
>
> Printed in Subclass

In other case (you are not overriding it, just using it), just write `this.methodName(...)`. All methods inherited are directly available.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not sure I totally understand your question. I will still try to answer what I think I understand.

The `Product` in package `com.franceFactory.services` (Lets call it `A`)
extends The `Product` class in package `com.services` (Lets call it `B`)

So A extends B.

B has method `deleteProduct(java.lang.Long)`

A overrides the method `deleteProduct(java.lang.Long)`

You have instance of Class A. So by OOPS concept method `deleteProduct` of object A is going to get called.

There is no way you can call the super method from outside unless you have the instance of class B.

**EDIT**

OPs Clarification `yes, it's public, but it isn't overridden in my class`

The method in super is getting called here. The product is not getting deleted for reason on what is written on the method.